# Remove TextFormField Extra space between widget and keyboard

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a TextFormField when the user clicks on it there is a huge space in between comes. As keyboard opening adds padding.

This is my widget tree

[image]

[image]

Code

```
TextFormField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: TextStyle(color: text_color, fontSize: 14),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    fillColor: appBackground_color,
                                    filled: true,
                                    focusColor: text_color,
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                   
                                    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                
                                    labelText: StringClass.ENTER_NAME),
                              ),
```

),

Comment: are you talking about padding inside textField, then use `decoration: InputDecoration(contentPadding: ),` or keyBoard vs layout

Comment: tried check the code in post @YeasinSheikh

Comment: having multiple `TextFiled` use `ValueKey` and `FocusNode`, does it solve in your case?

Comment: it does not work. Is it because of the stack? @YeasinSheikh

Comment: if wrap with positioned or aling, it will fulfill it;s promised spaces.